# Javascript search and replace not working

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a string like this,

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://9999.example.com.us/_vti_bin/MYServices/MYServices.svc/ ... so on .....
```

I want it to be this,

`"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://9999.example.com.us/myPart/myPart123/_vti_bin/MYServices/MYServices.svc/ ... so on`

These are large xml Odata responses and I am trying to replace base url as above, I tried this but it isn't working,

String.prototype.replaceAll = function (find, replace) {
    var str = this;
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/[-/\^$*+?.()|[]{}]/g, '\$&'), 'g'), replace);
};

```
string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base=https://9999.example.com.us/_vti_bin/MYServices/MYServices.svc';
string = string.replaceAll('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base=https://9999.example.com.us/_vti_bin/MYServices/MYServices.svc',
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base=https://9999.example.com.us/myPart/myPart123/_vti_bin/MYServices/MYServices.svc');
$('#result').html(string);
```

**Update**

I just want to add this part to the url, "/myPart/myPart123/"

http://jsfiddle.net/cdbzL/509/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this sample will help you:

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://9999.example.com.us/_vti_bin/MYServices/MYServices.svc/';

xml.replace(/_vti_bin/img, 'myPart/myPart123/_vti_bin');
```

You can use only `replace()` function to do that. [Read more about It](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

**And replace `$('#result').html(string)` with `$('#result').text(string)`.**

Some words about your `String.prototype.replaceAll = function() {}`:

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)**: Augmenting built-in objects through the prototype is a powerful technique, and
>   you can use it to shape JavaScript in any way you like. Because of its
>   power, though, you should always thoroughly consider your options
>   before using this approach. The reason is that once you know
>   JavaScript, you're expecting it to work the same way, no matter which
>   third-party library or widget you're using. Modifying core objects
>   could confuse the users and maintainers of your code and create
>   unexpected errors.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdbzL/511/)**

Comment: I am accepting your answer, but I will test it later on, on my system, thank you